# React Help - Why do i need to click twice to update state and call function?

Tags: reactjs

I have some buttons within my app that call handleTypeChange function below - my issue is that i have to click them twice for them to update state and call the getCOBs function correctly.

Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

```
    handleTypeChange(event){
    this.setState({filtertype: event.target.getAttribute('value')});
  
      if (event.target.getAttribute('value') === "Commercial")
      {
        this.setState({filtercommercial: 'True'});
        this.setState({filterpackage: 'False'});    
      }
      else if (event.target.getAttribute('value') === "Package")
      {
        this.setState({filtercommercial: 'False'});
        this.setState({filterpackage: 'True'});    
      }
      else{
        this.setState({filtercommercial: 'False'});
        this.setState({filterpackage: 'False'});    
      }
      getCOBs(this.state.filtercommercial, this.state.filterpackage).then(populateCOBDropdown);
      
    }
```

Comment: setState() does not immediately change state it creates a pending state transition. Accessing state right after calling setState method may give the previousState value., can you try calling getCOB without the state like getCOB(true, true) to check if the issue is related to state updation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.setState` function needs some time to save the states.

```
handleTypeChange(event){
  const value = event.target.getAttribute('value');
  this.setState({
    filtertype: value,
    filtercommercial: value === "Commercial"? "True" : "False",
    filterpackage: value === "Package"? "True" : "False",
  }, () => {
    getCOBs(this.state.filtercommercial, this.state.filterpackage).then(populateCOBDropdown);
  });          
}
```

The `callback` function of `this.setState` will be called after `states` are updated.